# Cannot display Mobfox ad on iPad using Google Admob Mediation

Tags: ios, admob, mobfox

I was able to integrate Mobfox (Adapter v4.1.0) using Google Admob Mediation (v6.2.1) on iPhone (the ad show and I can tap on it). But on iPad, nothing appear as I get the following error :

```
Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks."UserInfo=0x1ddd37c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks.}
```

This seems to mean there is no available Mobfox ad for Google Mediation to display. Did someone experienced the same issue ?

Note: I'm using the same Mobfox app ID for both but different Admob Mediation app.

Comment: From Mediation app's settings : `"Not all ad networks offer every ad size. Depending on the ad size you select, your network options may be limited."`. Does anyone know if Mobfox does propose iPad ad with Mediation ? Does anyone could include Mobfox with Admob Mediation on iPad ?

Comment: If you're asking about 728x90 leaderboards, the MobFox adapter is supposed to support it. If you created a 728x90 leaderboard mediation placement on iOS, you can see the list of supported networks.

Comment: I'm asking about 728x90 leaderboards. Where can I see this list of supported networks you're talking about ? Did you succeeded in including Mobfox with Mediation ?